# Animate different corners in CAShapeLayer

Tags: swift, xcode, cashapelayer

I am using the following code:

```
let MainLayer : CAShapeLayer = {
    let mainlayer = CAShapeLayer()
    mainlayer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    mainlayer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    mainlayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.0, height: 3.0)
    mainlayer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    mainlayer.shadowRadius = 7
    return mainlayer
}()
var LayerRect:CGRect!
var bezierPath:UIBezierPath!
let CellHeightMargin:CGFloat = 6.0
let CellWidthMargin:CGFloat = 15.0


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    LayerRect = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.origin.y, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - CellWidthMargin * 2, height: self.bounds.height - CellHeightMargin * 2)
    bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: LayerRect, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight,.topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
    MainLayer.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    self.mainView.layer.insertSublayer(MainLayer, at: 0)

}
```

As you can see, byRoundingCorners is to bottom right and top right corners, now I want to replace it by the bottom left and bottom right with animation. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the following:

```
    let ToStatusLayerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CellView.statusView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomRight,.bottomLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.toValue   = ToStatusLayerPath.cgPath
    animation.duration  = 1.0;
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    statusLayer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```